# JS: изменить стиль display по таймеру

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Я не очень сильна в JS, помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос. 
Есть div, который нужно отображать каждые условно 5 минут

**Неактивный div**

```
<div class="ibx-wpfomo-floating-popup" style="display: none; bottom: 90px; opacity: 0;">
```

**Активный div**

```
<div class="ibx-wpfomo-floating-popup" style="display: block; bottom: 100px; opacity: 1;">
```

*Как я понимаю, все просто: мне нужно с помощью setInterval изменить стиль css c display: none на display: block. Но почему-то код не работает.*

**Мой код:** (вставляю его в custom JS в настройках темы)

```
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
setTimeout(function (){
$(‘.ibx-wpfomo-floating-popup’).css('display', 'block');
}, 1000)
});
```

Буду признательна подсказкам :)

Answer (score 0):

Пример с добавлением класса `show` и соответствующими стилями:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  setTimeout(function (){
    $(".ibx-wpfomo-floating-popup").addClass('show');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.ibx-wpfomo-floating-popup {
  display: none; 
  bottom: 90px; 
  opacity: 0;
}

.ibx-wpfomo-floating-popup.show {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

  <div class="ibx-wpfomo-floating-popup" >Popup</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось!

Answer (score 0):

Если вы сами пишите, что использовать надо `setInterval`, то почему используете `setTimeout` ? Переключение `display` с `none` на `block` осуществляется с помощью метода `toggle`

```
setInterval(function(){
   $(".ibx-wpfomo-floating-popup").toggle(true);
}, 5*1000);
```